# How to hide developer option from setting except with clear data or factory reset on android 8.1.0?

Tags: settings, developer-options

I'm using clear data but the developer options is still there, the phone is vivo y81

Comment: Mostly ROMs have a toggle switch inside Developer Options to disable them. Or may use `settings put global development_settings_enabled 0` from adb or terminal emulator.

Comment: it only disable the developer settings, not hide it

Comment: It does both at least on Pie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the settings through an adb shell. That should hide the developer settings to make it like them hidden like before you enabled them:

`adb shell pm clear com.android.settings`

Comment: on coolpad it works, but on vivo it doesn't, is there any other solutions?

Comment: vivo android version is 8.1.0

Comment: it says not found

Comment: Well then how about listing every thing with the command `adb shell pm list packages`

Comment: https://justpaste.it/6ldjw

Comment: Alright, I had the package name correct. I do not think they changed the syntax with oreo. I will look into this.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Use a file manager from the play store such as FX file explorer. Then go into the system (/) and navigate to the system folder lastly navigate to the bin folder (path being /system/bin/ ). Within the bin folder you will see a lot of files look for one file named `clear` and one file named `pm` let me know if they are both there in the bin folder.

Comment: nevermind, i found the way using this method https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yGPx7wcleiw

Comment: looks like vivo indeed do something about the settings, thanks for the help, appreciated